# JBoss, Tomcat or Glassfish for Bonita Open Solution 5.4?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, workflow, glassfish

I'm currently trying to implement BOS 5.4 in one of my projects. Unfortunately I'm quite new with Java-based applications.

It is my understanding that you could implement BOS 5.4 either in JBoss, Glassfish or Apache Tomcat. There are a lot of documentation available online but I cannot determine which one to use. What is the recommended setup for a BOS installation?

Here's the setup that we are planning:
Bonita Open Solution 5.4
CAS for user authentication
MySQL for database
Integration with Liferay Portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use any server (which you counted), but if version of server does not matter for you, you can download JBoss 5.1 or Tomcat 6.0.29 with already installed BOS:

[Download BPM software and documentation](http://www.bonitasoft.com/products/BPM_download.php) page, go to the Bundles item.

using bundles can save you time for installation (I don't know how easy it is, never did), as well as you won't deal with conflicts (e.g. if current release does not work well with JBoss 6 because of its newer Hibernate or something else). Well, as I wrote, if server version does not matter, then go with bundle (imho). If your project already uses any server, then you could try to setup BOS there...

One more issue: if you don't need application container (like JBoss), then go with Tomcat, it is lightweight web server, it will be booted faster and needs less resources. If Tomcat is not enough for you, then JBoss is your choice. At least from what you wrote, I don't see anything that demands JBoss...

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish Server offers built-in high availability, command line and GUI management interfaces (no XML editing), with commercial support available - or you can use the open source builds.  It is also *very* well documented:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/documentation/index.html